# "The following packages have been kept back" not working "--with-new-pkgs" on Debian 11

Tags: linux, debian, apt, upgrade

Each time, I tried to upgrade my system I had loads of packages that have been kept back:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python3-async-timeout python3-pytest-asyncio python3-testpath
  python3-typing-extensions
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  evolution evolution-common evolution-data-server evolution-plugin-bogofilter
  evolution-plugin-pstimport evolution-plugins folks-common
  gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gnome gnome-calendar gnome-contacts gnome-control-center
  gnome-control-center-data gnome-core gnome-maps gnome-settings-daemon
  gnome-settings-daemon-common gnome-shell gnome-shell-common
  gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-shell-extensions gnome-weather
  gsettings-desktop-schemas libcamel-1.2-62 libebackend-1.2-10
  libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libevolution
  libgweather-3-16 libsemanage-common passwd udisks2
```

Firstly, I executed the command below to remove the unneeded packages:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Next I tried:

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

...but nothing changed. So I decided to install the packages mannually:

```
sudo apt install evolution evolution-common evolution-data-server evolution-plugin-bogofilter evolution-plugin-pstimport evolution-plugins folks-common gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gnome gnome-calendar gnome-contacts
```

However, I got this error:

```
(gnome-control-center:10099): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 14:07:35.779: Settings schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap

(org.gnome.Weather:10117): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:07:35.913: This application can not open files.
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I installed `fwupd` according to this [post](https://itsfoss.com/following-packages-have-been-kept-back/):

```bsh
$ sudo apt install fwupd
fwupd is already the newest version (1.5.7-5).
fwupd set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-getting-started-docs libcamel-1.2-62 libedataserver-1.2-25 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libhandy-0.0-0
```

I executed again and again:

```bsh
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt upgrade
The following packages have been kept back:
  libsemanage-common passwd udisks2
$ sudo apt install libsemanage-common passwd udisks2
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  exfat-fuse
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt upgrade
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Solved!